# How do programs like vi, man or less handle output?

Tags: command-line, output

How do those commands output to stdout? I could use the printf() function in C, but that would only add more characters to the screen instead of replacing any in a given location in the terminal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They use the `ncurses` (or a similar) library:

> The `ncurses` library routines give the user a terminal-independent method of updating character screens with reasonable optimization. This implementation is "new curses" (`ncurses`) and is the approved replacement for 4.4BSD classic `curses`, which has been discontinued

Check

- [`ncurses` official Website](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/announce.html)
- [Getting Started with ncurses](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/getting-started-ncurses)
- [Best ncurses linux console programs](https://www.etcwiki.org/wiki/Best_ncurses_linux_console_programs)
- [How Do ncurses et. al. Work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7558348/how-do-ncurses-et-al-work/7571408) (Stackoverflow)
- [How do some tools (e.g. nano , less) manage to leave no content in terminals after exit?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/336609/how-do-some-tools-e-g-nano-less-manage-to-leave-no-content-in-terminals-aft) (Unix&Linux SE)